# Update Notification Reminders

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

Im trying to tracking in sent evelope list 4 columns, for the parameters notification- reminders,
I added the following columns to the list that already showed EnvId, Name , Email, Status, etc
@envelope.Notification.Expirations.ExpireAfter                               @envelope.Notification.Expirations.ExpireWarn
@envelope.Notification.Reminders.ReminderDelay
@envelope.Notification.Reminders.ReminderFrequency

it doesn't show error, but they are empty in view, those 4 columns.
according to debugging, the method updateNotification works well, it is able to update the 4 parameters of notif-reminder (mentioned above) according to the parameters entered in the frontend

I wonder if maybe "include" in options is missing somewhere.

Comment: Tagging users like that doesn't work, but even if it did it's [not appropriate to do so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415156/150605) as your question is no more important than anybody else's.  Instead, if you want your question to get seen and answered you should focus on making sure it's formatted properly and takes advantage of the tagging system instead of putting keywords in the title.

Comment: Are you using envelopesApi.UpdateNotificationSettings() ? can you please share your code in the question?

Comment: I don't understand your question. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In listStatusChange method, we can have Notification Collection as reponse in Envelope. I had a list that works well showing Recipients Collections , Env Status, etc.; in a view with the model Envelope, now Im trying to add 4 columns with expireAfter, expwarning, reminderDelai and reminderFrequency in Notifications Collections, when I put the code in the view there is no error but the columns in the view are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer to [how to include Notification in listStatusChange method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72102883/how-to-include-notification-in-liststatuschange-method/72102945?noredirect=1#comment127402370_72102945)
It's the same answer:

The only way would be to make a GetNotificationSettings call for each **envelopeId**.