# how to include Notification in listStatusChange method

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I use ListStatusChange method to track the sent envelopes in my app.
So, I get a list including Recipients collection, the different columns in the view are shown in the following code. The view uses Envelope as Model

The problem is that I just added the last four columns for Notification Collection and even if the code doesn't give any error, in the view the columns are empty. If someone could help me please?

```
<table id="Envelopestbl" class="table table-hover ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th > EnvelopeID </th>                         
                            <th> Offices </th>
                            <th> Templates </th>
                            <th> Signer name </th>
                            <th> Signer email </th>
                            <th> Envelope status  </th>
                            <th> Envelope Last Update </th>
                            <th> Expire After</th>
                            <th> Expire Warning </th>
                            <th> Reminder Delai </th>
                            <th> Reminder Frequency </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if (Model != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var envelope in Model)
                            {
                                
                        <tr>
                            <td >@envelope.EnvelopeId</td>                                                       
                            <td >@envelope.OfficeName</td>
                            <td >@envelope.TemplateName</td>

                            @if (@envelope.Recipients.Signers.Count > 0)
                            {
                                <td> @envelope.Recipients.Signers[0].Name</td>
                                <td> @envelope.Recipients.Signers[0].Email</td>
                                
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                
                            }
                              
                            <td >@envelope.Status</td>
                            <td >@envelope.StatusChangedDateTime.AsDateTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</td>

                            @if(@envelope.Notification != null )
                            {
                                <td >@envelope.Notification.Expirations.ExpireAfter</td>
                                <td >@envelope.Notification.Expirations.ExpireWarn</td>
                                <td >@envelope.Notification.Reminders.ReminderDelay</td>
                                <td >@envelope.Notification.Reminders.ReminderFrequency</td>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td> </td>
                                <td> </td>
                                <td> </td>
                                <td> </td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-danger" style="text-align:center">
                                    <h4>There are no envelopes in this mailing</h4> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear like this can be done with [ListStatusChanges](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/).

The only way would be to make a [GetNotificationSettings](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/getnotificationsettings/) call for each **envelopeId**.

This is not ideal and would require too many API calls, so you may want to reconsider your application design.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand your answer,  I was considering like that , with getnotifsettings